# Wrap/unwrap div in to another div on scroll jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to wrap div in to another div using jQuery on scroll and then unwrap when scroll back, but every time I scroll its keep wrapping div, How do I make it work to once only?

This is the code I am trying

```
$(".scroller").scroll(function() {
    if($(window).width() > 768)
    {
    if($(".scroller").scrollTop() > 245) {
       $(".doctor_listing_wrapper").wrap("<div class='doctor_listing_wrapper_master'></div>");
      }   
      else{
       $(".doctor_listing_wrapper").unwrap("<div class='doctor_listing_wrapper_master'></div>");
      }
    }
});
```

The HTML is simple, just a div with some inner content

```
 <div class="doctor_listing_wrapper">
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
 </div>
```

**Update** [JSfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/nm8q1Lnf/1/)

Comment: Can you make a simple snippet using [JSBin](http://jsbin.com) to show your issue?

Comment: Just updated my question with the JSfiddle demo

Comment: Okay... I guess you got the answer already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to check, if the element already exists... the following example should resolve your problem (`!$(".doctor_listing_wrapper_master").length`)

```js
$(".scroller").scroll(function() {
    if($(window).width() > 768)
    {
    if($(".scroller").scrollTop() > 245) {
      if(!$(".doctor_listing_wrapper_master").length){
           $(".doctor_listing_wrapper").wrap("<div class='doctor_listing_wrapper_master'></div>");
        }
      }   
      else{
       $(".doctor_listing_wrapper").unwrap("<div class='doctor_listing_wrapper_master'></div>");
      }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="doctor_listing_wrapper">
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but unfortunately is removing the parent div, not sure how

Comment: actually its wrapping well now, but not unwrapping correctly

Comment: I figured it out, the problem was with unwrap I was trying wrong way, thanks again for the answer